# Scammed by bitcoin mining

Tags: bitcoind, mining-profitability

[image: bitcoin mining scammer]
This Instagram account managed to scam me into sending bitcoin to the miner she said would make me money. I explained I was a novice and she said she would help me through the process, she then blocked me after three weeks of telling me I need to add more money to it and open up "dormant miners" she said people had abandoned for no reason. When I asked for my money she blocked me .what can I do to stop others being scammed by her instagram doesn't care .
How can I stop this account scamming other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **what can I do to stop others being scammed by her**

Very little.

She probably isn't real, the account is almost-certainly fake. That isn't her  photo it is probably a stock photo or stolen from a web-page somewhere. The scammer might not be a woman.

Just as you probably didn't look at this independent website (bitcoin.stackexchange.com) before "investing" in bitcoin mining, so other future victims are likely to walk into this without really looking around and educating themselves about "bitcoin mining".

Maybe you could get your local news media to write a story about your experience. That *might* save one or two people from losing money.

This website already has [many stories similar to yours](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfraud%5D+miner).